# Swift 5: Why is my data within struct suddenly empty / nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct, urlsession

### Update:

The main thing I wonder about, is, that I'm able to log `self.schedule (.monday)` after the download JSON function successfully, but instantly gets `nil` when the tables should be refreshed.

[image: The tiny Xcode window also shows that <code>schedule</code> is <code>nil</code>.]

### Problem

There are currently two separate UITableViews in my  `ScheduleViewController`, where the tables should be filled differently with the downloaded data by the view controller it's `downloadSchedule()` function.

After a successful `URLSession` task, the received data will be stored in new variable called `json` and is printed in the console afterwards. Everything works well.

Now, when the `downloadSchedule()` function finished it's request and the next function to reload the tables is called, I want to count the the data for `numberOfRowsInSection`, but I'm getting a `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`.

Although the variable was previously filled with the downloaded data, it is now suddenly empty when I want to update the tables. How can this happen?

### Code

**I declare my variable in my `ScheduleViewController` like so:**

```
var schedule: Schedule?
```

**The `downloadSchedule()` function gets executed after `viewDidLoad()`:**

```
func downloadSchedule(completed: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "example.com/meta/schedule")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, error in
        if error == nil {
            do {
                self.schedule = try JSONDecoder().decode(Schedule.self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("executed")
                    completed()
                }
            } catch {
                print("JSON Error")
            }
        }

    }.resume()
}

downloadSchedule {
    self.mondayTableView.reloadData()
    self.tuesdayTableView.reloadData()
}
```

**An example what happens first to update the tables:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

    var count:Int?

    if tableView == self.mondayTableView {
        count = schedule?.monday.count
    }

    if tableView == self.tuesdayTableView {
        count =  schedule?.tuesday.count
    }

    return count!

}
```

**These are my structs for Schedule and Day:**

```
// MARK: - Schedule
struct Schedule: Codable {
    let monday: [Day]
    let tuesday: [Day]
    let wednesday: [Day]
    let thursday: [Day]
    let friday: [Day]
    let saturday: [Day]
    let sunday: [Day]
    let nextmonday: [Day]
    let nexttuesday: [Day]
    let nextwednesday: [Day]
    let nextthursday: [Day]
    let nextfriday: [Day]
    let nextsaturday: [Day]
    let nextsunday: [Day]
    let airtimeAPIVersion: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday, nextmonday, nexttuesday, nextwednesday, nextthursday, nextfriday, nextsaturday, nextsunday
        case airtimeAPIVersion = "AIRTIME_API_VERSION"
    }
}

// MARK: - Day
struct Day: Codable {
    let startTimestamp: String?
    let endTimestamp: String?
    let name: String?
    let dayDescription: String?
    let id: Int?
    let instanceID: Int?
    let instanceDescription: String?
    let record: Int?
    let url: String?
    let imagePath: String?
    let starts: String?
    let ends: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case startTimestamp = "start_timestamp"
        case endTimestamp = "end_timestamp"
        case name = "name"
        case dayDescription = "description"
        case id = "id"
        case instanceID = "instance_id"
        case instanceDescription = "instance_description"
        case record = "record"
        case url = "url"
        case imagePath = "image_path"
        case starts = "starts"
        case ends = "ends"
    }
}
```

### JSON

```
{
  "monday": [
    {
      "start_timestamp": "2020-06-01 01:35:00",
      "end_timestamp": "2020-06-01 01:37:37",
      "name": "TEST",
      "description": "",
      "id": 174,
      "instance_id": 950,
      "instance_description": "",
      "record": 0,
      "url": "",
      "image_path": "example.com/api/show-logo?id=174",
      "starts": "2020-06-01 01:35:00",
      "ends": "2020-06-01 01:37:37"
    }
  ],
  "tuesday": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't to return potential nil in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method. Because it should be called at initial tableview load data and 100% you will get crash. You may return `0`.

So:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Return the number of items in the sample data structure.

    guard let schedule = schedule else { return 0 }

    var count:Int = 0

    if tableView == self.mondayTableView {
        count = schedule.monday.count
    }

    if tableView == self.tuesdayTableView {
        count = schedule.tuesday.count
    }

    return count

}
```

Also, are you sure that

- `schedule.monday` or `. tuesday` is not nil after loadData?
- `self.schedule` is nil in the `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection`?
- you don't have more than 2 tableViews with this `UITableViewDelegate` (in this
  viewcontroller)?

Also completion handler in your `loadData` will be newer called if you get an error of url request or parsing json. Add `completed()` to this places or move your one to the bottom:

```
func downloadSchedule(completed: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api/....")

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, _, error in
        if error == nil,
            let data = data {
            do {
                self.schedule = try JSONDecoder().decode(Schedule.self, from: data)
                print("JSON \(self.schedule?.monday)")
            } catch {
                print("JSON Error")
            }
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completed()
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

Comment: When I update my URLSession function following yours, none of them print functions getting executed. To your questions, `schedule.monday` was not nil after the `downloadSchedule()` at first place, as I was able to print it but gets instantly nil when the table update functions getting called. Here's the full source code: https://github.com/dmnktoe/radio-rasclat-ios/blob/schedule/RadioRasclat/Views/Schedule/ScheduleViewController.swift

Comment: Thank you! It was easy - I just forget to write guard at begin of method. Сheck it!

Comment: Also its better to setup delegates and registers cells and only then load data (in your viewDidLoad)

Comment: Mate, that works. Thank you very much! Can you tell me what I did wrong and provide me an example "to setup delegates and registers cells and only then load data (in your viewDidLoad)"?

Comment: just place 
downloadSchedule {
    self.mondayTableView.reloadData()
    self.tuesdayTableView.reloadData()
}
AFTER strings where you assign the delegate&datasource&register cells. (at the bottom of method)
Because when you do tableView.reloadData, these things ALREADY should be done.
In most cases its not critical, but sometimes you can get something not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You never assigned anything to `self.schedule`

These two lines:

```
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Schedule.self, from: data!)
print(json)
```

don't change the value of `self.schedule`.  You need to write

```
self.schedule = try JSONDecoder().decode(Schedule.self, from: data!)
```

When you do: `JSONDecoder().decode(Schedule.self, from: data!)`

That means "data is a bunch of bytes that are JSON, parse it into a Schedule value and return it."

In that line `Schedule.self` is the type we are trying to parse it as -- it has nothing to do with `self.schedule`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but even with that approach the variable is still empty as soon as the `func tableView` gets called. I updated my `downloadSchedule()` function, because I forgot to put my completion handler into the function.